# Bulk rename, change prefix

Tags: rename, filenames

How can I bulk replace the prefix for many files?

I have a lot of files like

- TestSRConnectionContext.h
- TestSRConnectionContext.m

I would like to change all them to

- CLConnectionContext.h
- CLConnectionContext.m

How would I do this?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

```
for name in TestSR*
do
    newname=CL"$(echo "$name" | cut -c7-)"
    mv "$name" "$newname"
done
```

This uses bash command substitution to remove the first 6 characters from the input filename via `cut`, prepends `CL` to the result, and stores that in `$newname`. Then it renames the old name to the new name. This is performed on every file.

`cut -c7-` specifies that only characters after index 7 should be returned from the input. `7-` is a range starting at index 7 with no end; that is, until the end of the line.

Previously, I had used `cut -b7-`, but `-c` should be used instead to handle character encodings that could have multiple bytes per character, like UTF-8.

Comment: Thx, i got this right now by myself too. Marking as answer. Thx

Comment: This works nicely, thanks. Can you explain what the -b7- does? Is this reference to the byte-list? http://www.ss64.com/bash/cut.html

Comment: @imjared Updated the answer with more details.

Comment: @mrb, how can I change this command to work for all folders and all files in the current directory?

Answer (score 83):

I'd say the simplest it to just use the `rename` command which is common on many Linux distributions.  There are two common versions of this command so check its man page to find which one you have:

```
## rename from Perl (default in Debian systems -- Ubuntu, Mint, ...)
rename 's/^TestSR/CL/' TestSR*

## rename from util-linux-ng (common in Fedora systems, Red Hat, CentOS, ...)
rename TestSR CL TestSR*
```

Using a `TestSR*` shell wildcard as opposed to just `*` helps in that it potentially passes far fewer file names to `rename` and reduces the risk of running into a *Argument list too long* error, but also and more importantly avoids problems when there are file names that start with `-` in the current working directory. It's particularly important for some of the `perl`-based variants of `rename` where not doing so introduces command injection vulnerabilities.

Comment: A caveat: multiple versions of `rename` exist in the wild.  Check your local `rename` documentation to figure out how to use yours.

Comment: To remove the alias do `rename TestSR '' *`

Comment: hmm... `rename "\<pre\>" "" *` -> `Unterminated <> operator at (user-supplied code).`

Comment: @FlashThunder, your `rename` is one of the perl variants, so you'd need `rename 's/<pre>//' ./*'<pre>'*` to remove the first occurrence of `<pre>` in each file name or `rename 's/<pre>//g' ./*'<pre>'*` to remove all of them.

Answer (score 43):

[Shell parameter expansion](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02) is enough for simple transformations like this.  Command substitution is less efficient because of the need to spawn extra processes (for the command substitution itself and the `cut`/`sed`).

```
for f in TestSR*; do mv "$f" "CL${f#TestSR}"; done
```

Comment: Explanation: `TestSR*` finds the files, `CL${f#TestSR}` will be the new name. The stuff after the `#` will be substituted from the filename (`f`).

Answer (score 4):

Here's one way:

```
ls *.{h,m} | while read a; do n=CL$(echo $a | sed -e 's/^Test//'); mv $a $n; done
```

- `ls *.{h,m}` --> Find all files with .h or .m extension
- `n=CL` --> Add a CL prefix to the file name
- `sed -e 's/^Test//'` --> Removes the Test prefix from the file name
- `mv $a $n` --> Performs the rename

Answer (score 4):

You can try with:

```
for i in TestSR*; do mv "$i" "${i/#TestSR/CL}"; done
```

See `man bash` (section "Parameter Expansion") for details.

Should also work in ksh93 (where that syntax initially comes from) and zsh.

Answer (score 2):

Well, it wasn't as hard as i though.

```
$ for f in TestSR*.m; do mv $f CL$(echo $f | cut -c7-); done;
$ for f in TestSR*.h; do mv $f CL$(echo $f | cut -c7-); done;
```

Comment: In case it helps for the future, you don't have to repeat the commands for your two patterns; you can use (for example): `for f in TestSR*.[mh]`, `for f in TestSR*.{m,h}`, `for f in TestSR*.m TestSR*.h`.

Answer (score 1):

If you need something more perlish you can do this

```
perl -e 'for(@ARGV) { rename($_, $n) if( ($n = $_ ) =~ s/^TestSR/CL/) }' *
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't like any of the answers. My take is that you want a vanilla bash solution. So here you go!

Try this with echo first to see what is going to happen! Test your command before you use it on thousands of files!

**Remove the './' is you want to put a prefix**
`find . -type f -exec bash -c 'echo prefix_${0#./}' {} \;`

**Remove the extension if you want to put something after it**
`find . -type f -exec bash -c 'echo ${0%.*}_suffix.${0##*.}' {} \;`

Now to use this to rename just replace echo with `mv $0`

EXAMPLE: `find . -type f -exec bash -c 'mv $0 1.${0#./}' {} \;`

Inspired by: https://gist.github.com/larshaendler/723d2ec447c3c694b71dc6e3bc3aadc9

Comment: The way you wrote this, (nine years later:-), with `find . ... {} \;` you would be spawning separate bash subshells for each of the thousands of files you may find. That could make things very slow.

Comment: @Chota That depends on the requirements. In my experience the usage of `-exec` has never been really slow on huge tasks. And yes it could be faster. The question was "how can I bulk rename with prefix for many files" and not how to bulk rename in the fastest most efficient way. I would say: if you want something for a bash script, then use the `for loop` method. If you want something you can type in from the top of your head to quickly operate in a terminal, learn the above structure. It's powerful and generic.

Answer (score 0):

Obligatory answer using zsh's zmv:

```
autoload -Uz zmv # best in ~/.zshrc
zmv -n 'TestSR(*.[hm])' 'CL$1'
```

Remove the `-n` (for dry-run) if happy.