# Bulk renaming filenames containing space with Linux built-in tool

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, shell

I've been reading about [Bulk rename, change prefix](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/47367/bulk-rename-change-prefix) and would try with my own files.

In this case, I would like to remove `Old` and replace it with `New`

**Test Files**

```
01. Old Name.txt
02. Old Name.txt
03. Old Name.txt
```

**Attempt 1**

```
for f in *.txt
do
    mv "$f" "New${f#Old}"
done
```

**Output 1**

```
New01. Old Name.txt
New02. Old Name.txt
New03. Old Name.txt
```

**Attempt 2**

```
for i in *.txt
do
    mv ${i} ${i/#Old/New}
done
```

**Output 2 (no changes)**

```
user@linux:~$ for i in *.txt
> do
> mv ${i} ${i/#Old/New}
> done
mv: target 'Name.txt' is not a directory
mv: target 'Name.txt' is not a directory
mv: target 'Name.txt' is not a directory
user@linux:~$
```

What's wrong with my solution?

**Desired Output**

```
01. New Name.txt
02. New Name.txt
03. New Name.txt
```

Comment: Just use the perl `rename` command.  It's just as "built-in" as the `mv` command.  i.e. neither of them are "built-in" to bash, they're both external commands run from the shell.   And, like GNU `coreutils` (which contains `mv`), it's available pre-packaged for most, if not all, linux distributions.   `rename 's/Old/New/' *.txt`

Comment: BTW, your 2nd attempt fails because you didn't double-quote the arguments.   Try `mv "${i}" "${i/Old/New}"`.    See [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters)

Comment: Thanks @cas. If I quote it, I'll get this error `mv: '01. Old Name.txt' and '01. Old Name.txt' are the same file`

Comment: `rename` is not built-in .. need to install it. I've problem with a few servers whereby we cannot simply install anything new to it

`Command 'rename' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo apt install rename
`

Comment: as i pointed out, `mv` is not "built-in" either.

Comment: also, did you try `mv "${i}" "${i/Old/New}"` as i suggested, or with a `#` like `mv "${i}" "${i/#Old/New}"` as in your attempt 2?   The former will work. The latter won't.

Comment: I did, see my 2nd comment above. This will produce error `mv: '01. Old Name.txt' and '01. Old Name.txt' are the same file`

Comment: no, it doesn't.  see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Quote your variables.   Also, use `${i/Old/New}` without the hash character (`#`) before `Old`. The `#` forces the match to start at the beginning of the filename, but none of the files begin with `Old`, they all start with `0`.

   ```
   $ touch "01. Old Name.txt" "02. Old Name.txt" "03. Old Name.txt"
   $ for i in *.txt ; do mv -v "$i" "${i/Old/New}" ; done
   renamed '01. Old Name.txt' -> '01. New Name.txt'
   renamed '02. Old Name.txt' -> '02. New Name.txt'
   renamed '03. Old Name.txt' -> '03. New Name.txt'
   ```
2. Install and use the perl `rename` utility (e.g. `sudo apt-get install rename` on debian and derivatives).  It's far better than DIY bulk renaming.

Comment: Got it, there was extra `#` on my script .. thanks it works!

Comment: Also, use `mv -i` or `-n` on an automated/bulk move/rename operation like this, to avoid the risk of data loss in case there are any name conflicts (or mistakes in the renaming).

Comment: and that's yet another reason to use the perl `rename` command.  It won't overwrite existing files unless you force it to with `-f`, `--force`.